# How to get weekend that starting in Friday 23:59:59 and ends in Sunday 23:59:59

Tags: c#

I want stop a piece of code over a weekend in Friday 23:59:59 until Sunday 23:59:59 and start it again when that time pass.

I tried like this to get day of week and time

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
string getDay = time.ToString("dddd"); // day of week full name Friday
string getTime = time.ToString("HH:mm:ss"); // current time 24h format
```

Now i don't know how to apply this to code to pause it until this time doesn't pass, and run code again.

Is there exists some function to check day and time between Friday 23:59:59 - Sunday 23:59:59.

Edit to @fubo answer

```
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        bool isWeekend = time.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || time.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday;

        if (isWeekend)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Weekend started");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Weekend didn't started");
        }
```

Comment: *Is there exists some function to check day and time between Friday 23:59:59 - Sunday 23:59:59.* no, you're going to have to write one yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `DayOfWeek` enum

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
bool isWeekend = time.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || time.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday;
```

Comment: This would fail on Friday 23:59:59

Comment: that said it depends on what OP wants...it's not 100% clear

Comment: @Liam this is more a mistake in the question but you can also add  `|| (time.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday && time.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(23,59,59));`

Comment: @fubo this i need to add for Sunday too ? in order to work like `|| (time.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday && time.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(23,59,59));` then i don't need to check for `|| time.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday;` in code ? check my question i edited it.

Comment: @Sanja no, just use the code in the answer - my and Liam's comment was about the one missing second on friday